# Sony QX10 connect over bluetooth

Tags: android, camera, sony

I'm developing an APP using the camera Sony QX10.
I did some tests and it worked well.
But, as I understand, it requires Wi-Fi to connect the device to the camera.
Is it possible to use Bluetooth instead?

The app needs to be used in a place without Wi-Fi, is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lens itself broadcasts a WiFi network, so you don't need an external WiFi network for your app to communicate with the lens.  Just connect your phone/tablet to the network that it's broadcasting and thats it.